# Trigger event in NgOninit on click in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, dom-events

I have a click event. And if you click on that you can fill a little form.

But I want as default value that if the page is loaded first time, that you already see the form. I try it in the `NgOninit`.

So I have this as **`html`**:

```
<button mat-button mat-icon-button #nodeInput (click)="addNode($event)"><mat-icon>add</mat-icon></button>
```

And this is the **method**:

```
 addNode(model?: SchemaTemplateNodeDTO) {
    const newControl = this.fb.control(model ? model : null, [Validators.required]);

    const node = {
      id: this.idGen++,
      children: []
    };

    // Add node to tree and form
    this.idToFormControl.set(node.id, newControl);

    const nodes = this.form.controls['nodes'] as FormArray;
    nodes.push(newControl);

    this.dataSource.data.push(node);

    // Refresh tree
    this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data;
  }
```

and I have it now in the `NgOniti` like **this**:

```
@ViewChild('nodeInput' ) fileInput: ElementRef;
ngOnInit() {

    this.fileInput.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);

    this.addNode();

  }
```

if I try it like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();
  }
```

Then I will get this error:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="saveAndPublish()" [disabled]="form.invalid">Save & Publish</button>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="save()" [disabled]="form.invalid">Save</button>
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <app-node-tree-input formControlName="nodes"></app-node-tree-input>
</form>
```

So in a other component.

and this is part of the other component:

```
export class EditSchemaComponent implements OnInit {
  private schema: SchemaTemplateDTO;

  private fb: FormBuilder;
  form: FormGroup;

  public readonly displayedColumns = ["title", "published", "pages", "createdOnUtc", "createdBy", "edit"];

  constructor(
    private i18n: I18n,
    private schemaTemplateService: SchemaTemplateService,
    private blockerService: ScreenBlockerService,
    route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.schema = route.snapshot.data["schema"];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fb = new FormBuilder();
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      nodes: this.fb.control(this.schema.nodes)
    });
  }
```

Comment: why oh why are you using elementRef here?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `nativeElement.click()`:

```
this.fileInput.nativeElement.click()
```

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz so that we can reproduce

Comment: Can we go to chat.

Comment: Is that Oke? will be nice

Comment: I don't see the link of going to chat

Comment: Can you invite me?

Comment: The option comes after a long chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199571/discussion-between-mightycode-newton-and-adrita-sharma).

Comment: I am in the chat